# How To Get Netbox Plug-in Specific Filterset Values?

Tags: django, netbox

I’m building a Netbox plug-in, and have a filter form that looks the way that I want. But I want to give the user drop down options for each of the fields with the specific options that are available, and am unsure how to restrict the options to specific fields.

I found a way to show options via drop-down, but it doesn’t show the options specific for that field. It works so that if there are 20 fields for value D, but 30 total values (10 aren’t present), how would I build the filterset to only get those 20 values? What about if they are foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this through the use of the forms.py and filtersets.py